# Is the Wave Function a Unitary Operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, hilbert-space

A unitary operator can be represented as an exponential $$e^{iA}$$
and as we represent the wave function in general as $$e^{i k x}.$$ Does that mean that the wavefunction is unitary as the exponent is also a hermitian Operator?

Is this also the reason why we can switch the order of integration as the wavefunction is unitary?

Comment: The wave function isn't any operator let alone a unitary operator. An operator is something that acts on wave functions.

Comment: and what is "*Is this also the reason why we can switch the oder of integration as the wavefunction is unitary?*" supposed to mean?

Comment: since the square of the wave function is a probability distribution and probabilities integrate to 1 over the appropriate variables the functional form is bounded by this .

Comment: *"and as we represent the wave function in general as $e^{ikx}$"*  -   This isn't true.  However, $e^{ikx}$ *is* (the coordinate representation of) an operator - an operator that performs translations in momentum space.

Comment: The inner product on the state space allows you to identify the state space $S$ with its dual.  Therefore you can think of a single state (i.e. a single wave function) as a linear map $S\rightarrow{\mathbb C}$.  A unitary operator, by contrast, is a linear map $S\rightarrow S$.  So these are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wave function is an abstract mathematical function which could completely describe about the system under consideration. We define a wave function such that we could derive whatever information from it, provided that will not affect the state of the system. The wave function is not any operator. It's simply a function of position and time.

Any dynamical properties we use in classical physics, we term them as operators in quantum mechanics, like the momentum operator, energy operator etc. These operators acts on the wave function to give the value of the property of the system at that instant. When you operate the wave function by the momentum operator, you will get the momentum eigen value.

Comment: well, now everything is quite precise, but it's not so important in the context ("When you operate the wave function by the momentum operator" you get a new wave function, and the projection of the new on the old is your expectation value of the momentum)

Answer (score 0):

> and as we represent the wave function in general as $e^{ikx}$

This isn't true.  In general, we represent the wave function as

$$\psi(\mathbf{x}) = \langle\mathbf{x}|\psi\rangle$$

Only in the case that $|\psi\rangle = |\mathbf{p}\rangle$ (a momentum eigenstate) do we have

$$\psi(\mathbf{x}) = \langle\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{p}\rangle = e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathbf{p\cdot x}} = e^{i\mathbf{k \cdot x}}$$

Now, it's true that $e^{i\mathbf{k}' \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}}$ is an operator (note the hat over x) - an operator that is a function of the position operator.  A function of an operator is a function of the eigenvalue when operating on an eigenstate so

$$e^{i\mathbf{k}' \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}} |\mathbf{x}\rangle = e^{i\mathbf{k' \cdot x}}|\mathbf{x}\rangle$$

thus

$$\langle\mathbf{x}|e^{i\mathbf{k}' \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}} |\psi\rangle = e^{i\mathbf{k' \cdot x}}\psi(\mathbf{x})$$

So, this operator, when operating on wavefunction, returns the wavefunction multiplied by a position dependent phase.  What does this do?

Transform to $\mathbf{k}$ space and find that

$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int d^3k\: e^{i\mathbf{k' \cdot x}}\psi(\mathbf{x})e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}} = \phi(\mathbf{k} - \mathbf{k}')$$

where $\phi(\mathbf{k})$ is the Fourier transform of $\psi(\mathbf{x})$.  In short, the operator $e^{i\mathbf{k}' \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}}$ shifts the momentum components of the state by $\mathbf{p}' = \hbar \mathbf{k'}$.

But, and again, $e^{i\mathbf{k}' \cdot \hat{\mathbf{x}}}$ is an operator, not a wavefunction.